# Reading float numbers from a file in a special manner

Tags: c, file-io, floating-point, scanf

I'm trying to read numbers from the file in a 2D-Array, i have to skip the first row and first column, rest all have to save in an array, i've tried using sscanf, fscanf and even strtok() but failed miserably. So please help me to solve this issue.
Thanx in advance,

[Link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LawZAwfUJUcTVpWmYxclBuM0k/view)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
FILE *f=fopen("Monthly_Rainfall_Himachal.txt","r");
float data[12][12];
int i,j;
char newLine[1000];
fgets(newLine,1000,f);
char* item,waste;
i=0;
while(1)//read file line by line
{
    fscanf(f, "%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f ", waste, &data[i][0], &data[i][1], &data[i][2], &data[i][3], &data[i][4], &data[i][5], &data[i][6], &data[i][7], &data[i][8], &data[i][9], &data[i][10], &data[i][11]);
    i++;
    if(feof(f))break;
}
fclose(f);

for(i=0 ;i<12 ;i++){
    for(j=0 ;j<12 ;j++){
        printf("%.1f\t",data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not check the return value from `fscanf`?

Comment: `char waste` is a single `char` but the `%s` format needs an array. Even it it were `char* waste` (as you possibly imagine) there is no memory allocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems:

1. You don't check if the `fopen` was successful in opening the file or not and blindly assume it did.

   Check its return value:

   ```
   if(f == NULL)
   {
       fputs("fopen failed! Exiting...\n", stderr);
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   ```
2. Instead of reading *and storing* the first line, you can just read and discard it using `scanf`:

   ```
   scanf("%*[^\r\n]"); /* Discard everything until a \r or \n */
   scanf("%*c");       /* Discard the \r or \n as well */

   /* You might wanna use the following instead of `scanf("%*c")` 
      if there would be more than one \r or \n 

   int c;
   while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\r' && c != EOF);

      But note that the next fscanf first uses a `%s` which
      discards leading whitespace characters already. So, the
      `scanf("%*c");` or the while `getchar` loop is optional 
   */
   ```
3. You have an unused character pointer `item` and a character variable `waste`. Both of these are unnecessary. So, remove them.
4. In the very long `fscanf` line, you first try to scan in a string into a character variable which invokes Undefined Behavior and things go haywire. You also need to check its return value to see if it was successful.

   Replace that `fscanf` line with the following:

   ```
   if(fscanf(f, "%*s") == EOF)
   {
       fputs("End Of File! Exiting...\n", stderr);
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
   {
       if(fscanf(f, "%f", &data[i][j]) != 1)
       {
           fputs("End Of File or bad input! Exiting...\n", stderr);
           return EXIT_SUCCESS;
       }
   }
   ```
5. You assume the input is of a maximum of 12 lines, but if it contains more than 12 lines, your code will invoke Undefined Behavior due to an array overrun.

   Check the value of `i` along with the `feof` to make sure it does not go beyond 11:

   ```
   if(i >= 12 || feof(f))
   ```

<sup><sub>Note: I did not test any of the above code. Please correct me if I've made a mistake. Thanks!</sub></sup>